# Run ant target multiple times but replace fileset it refers to

Tags: ant, build.xml, fileset

I have an Ant target which runs unit tests on a fileset with a specific name, hardcoded inside of the target.

I would like to call that target multiple times, each time setting the fileset to a new value. I cannot change the name of the fileset which targets looks up, I can only define the fileset prior to calling a target.

Is it possible to call a target like this, and re-define same fileset during each target call?

Comment: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html Does the nested element `reference` work for you?

Comment: Some snippet would be helpful. So just guessing => if the "specific hardcoded name" means the id attribute of fileset use a macrodef with other fileset parameters (dir, includes, excludes ..) as attributes. AntCall should be avoided if possible.